# Glide - How to set size Placeholder equal size Image from URL before updating the ImageView

Tags: android, android-glide

I using Glide lib for load photo from url to show on ImageView.But this Photo have multiple size, i want before updating the ImageView then placeholder show with size equal size Image from URL.
Like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
    Glide.with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .override((int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._180sdp), (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._300sdp))
                    .fitCenter()
                    .bitmapTransform(new RoundedTransformation(context, (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._10sdp)))
                    .error(defaultImageResId)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(imageView);
```

How can do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the image dimensions from the server along with URL and use it to resize the place holder image.

```
Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .override(width, height) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel)
    .into(imageViewResize);
```

Comment: Dont work for me, many image so many size, i want placeholder show with size equal size Image from URL

Comment: Where are you getting the urls from?

Comment: https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/arubaitotest/images/1493264957079-201704271249.jpg
https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/arubaitotest/images/1493265748627-20170426_165852.jpg

Comment: If i use placeholder then photo in imageview only show same width and height with placeholder.

Comment: You should ask your server side guy to send you the dimensions along with URL. That's the only solution I guess